# Write xlsx columns below each other with Pandas Python3 xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have one excel(*.xlsx) file with three sheets. Every Sheet has a column named "Firma". I want to put them in a new xlsx file as one column all three below each other with only one column header on top "Firma". I tried concatinating like liste1_1['Firma'] + liste1_2['Firma'] + liste1_3['Firma'] but this puts the index 1 of all 3 columns in one row and the index 2 of all 3 columns in one row etc. But i want them below each other.

When i run this code:

```
import pandas as pd

liste1_1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\benja\Google Drive\Versandlisten\Mappe1.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
liste1_2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\benja\Google Drive\Versandlisten\Mappe1.xlsx', sheet_name=1)
liste1_3 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\benja\Google Drive\Versandlisten\Mappe1.xlsx', sheet_name=2)
a = liste1_1[['Firma']]
b = liste1_2[['Firma']]
c = liste1_3[['Firma']]
neu = [a,b,c]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\\Users\\benja\\Google Drive\\Versandlisten\\neu.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for x in neu:
    x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Gesamtliste', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Its putting only the colums of the last sheet in the excel But its not collecting all 3 columns completly below each other.

Cant show the data. But want to provide a example below:

**Sheet 1 of input:**

[image]
**Sheet 2 of input:**

[image]
**Sheet 3 of input:**

[image]

**Sheet 1 of result:**

[image]
Later on i want to take 5 or more excel files, read the columns named "Firma" and put it in one new list below the others. Same for different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your sheets are of the exact same structure (which it seems) you can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) in the following fashion:

```
pd.concat([liste1_1, liste1_2, liste1_3])
```

and then save the resulting data frame back to Excel:

```
df = pd.concat([liste1_1, liste1_2, liste1_3], sort=False) # avoiding the warning here

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\benja\Google Drive\Versandlisten\neu.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Gesamtliste', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: They are not. Column "Firma" can be in a other position like in Sheet1 of input. I tried pd.concat and get this error message: "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel." How can i pass 'sort=True' in?

Comment: It's just a warning, don't worry. You can get rid of it by doing either `pd.concat([liste1_1, liste1_2, liste1_3], sort=True)` or `pd.concat([liste1_1, liste1_2, liste1_3], sort=False)`.